# Let Debian Stretch Webserver respond on both nics

Tags: debian, nat, nic

I got **one** webserver with **two nics** in individual subnets **192.168.188.x** and **192.168.198.x**. This webserver is connected to 2 different routers (192.168.188.1 and 192.168.198.1) and via Portforwarding an Port 80 directly to the internet (each router has also an own public ip-address).

```
     (external ip)                Portforwarding:80                   (external ip)
    ---[ROUTER]----                                                  ---[ROUTER]----
     192.168.188.1               Router internal IP                   192.168.198.1        
           |                                                               |
           |                                                               |
           |                                                               |
           |                                                               |
           +------- 192.168.188.11:80 [WEBSERVER] 192.168.198.11:80 -------+
```

I' like to react the server on Port 80 for **both** subnets. Unfortunately, it responds in the default config only to the router wich is set as default gateway, wich is quite logically. But I need to act it to send the packets back to the interface, where the packets came frome. How to achieve this? There is no further configuration possibility above port forwarding on the routers e. g. for nat etc, anything needs to be done on the webserver, which is debian stretch.

Please keep in mind, that I'm only facing network problems about once in 10 years, so please make it simple. :)

Comment: this question is not put together with required information, like config of the network cards which routes rletc. moreover debian stretch has reached EOL and should be updated to buster asap

Answer (score 0):

If your webserver is properly configured to listen to 0.0.0.0:80 which you can check via `ss -l` then your problem is not the webserver configuration problem, but the routing problem. Only one route can be detected at once even if you have two. The only way to achieve what you want is to add second default route and use source policy routing. If the server is Linux it can be done via iptables. Try [this](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Adv-Routing-HOWTO/lartc.rpdb.simple.html) or [this](https://superuser.com/questions/376667/how-to-route-only-specific-subnet-source-ip-to-a-particular-interface).

Answer (score 0):

The solution requires the complex configuration of routing.

1. The web server should listen both (`192.168.188.11` and `192.168.198.11`) addresses or the `0.0.0.0` address, what means `all addresses`. Check it with `ss -tlnp sport == :80` command.
2. Create separate routing table for every *legs*:

```
ip route add 192.168.188.0/24 dev <iface1> table 1
ip route add 0/0 via 192.168.118.1 dev <iface1> table 1

ip route add 192.168.198.0/24 dev <iface2> table 2
ip route add 0/0 via 192.168.198.1 dev <iface2> table 2
```

3. Configure the route rules to route the replies through the same interface, through what the request has been received:

```
ip rule add from 192.168.188.11 lookup 1 pref 1000
ip rule add from 192.168.198.11 lookup 2 pref 2000
```

4. Troubleshooting:

- Use the `tcpdump -ni <iface> 'tcp port 80'` to sniff the traffic. At least you should see the http requests from outside.
- Check the route for **requests** with `ip route get <dst> from <src> iif <iface>`. It should show the `local` route. If it shows something else, check the `rp_filter` with `ip netconf show dev <iface>` command. It should be `off` or in the `loose` mode.
- Check the actual route for **replies** with `ip route get <dst> from <src-address>`, where the destination address is the source address of the **requests** you have seen in the `tcpdump` output.
- Check the firewall rules with command `iptables-save -c`. The configuration ***doesn't require*** any additional **nat** rules!